# TableAdapter FillBy Query with parameters doesn't work with LIKE operator

Tags: vb.net

Banging my head against a wall here.   I have a query that looks like this.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address
FROM Members
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'JOE%'
```

That works absolutely fine in query wizard and the DataTablePreview data window.  However, when I do this.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address
FROM Members
WHERE FirstName LIKE ?
```

I get nothing when I run the fillby method.  If I change the LIKE to =.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address
FROM Members
WHERE FirstName = ?
```

Everything works great.  I need to get LIKE working though so I can wildcard search.

I'm using the SQL server OLE db connections if that means anything.

UPDATE

Using the LIKE operator doesn't work at all.  When I just swap out = for LIKE.  Nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that something in the OLEDB connection was hosed up.  When I created a new connection and a new table adapter, everything started working fine.

**EDIT**

What I actually did was use the SQL server adapter instead of the SQL server OLEDB adapter.

DB

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to convert your query to :

```
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + ? + '%'
```

If you pass % within the parameter itself, I think it will interpret it as a string value rather than a wildcard and just work the same as FirstName = 'JOE%'

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. The query worked in the query builder and then when previewing it in the table adapter it failed.

I changed the SQL to be `LIKE LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))`

And then I put the `%` in the string that I was sending. The table adapter was sending the full string in the parameter, including spaces, even if the input was trimmed. This meant that the query would never find the data because of the spaces

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add the % to the param field?

Found at

- [Using 'like' in TableAdapter SQL
  statement with parameter](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/topic41736.aspx)
- [using the LIKE statement in a table
  adapter](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_22088461.html)